# Issue with Typescript exported namespaces and rollup

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I am converting some projects that used webpack to vite. I'm having a weird issue where rollup doesn't seem to recognize exported namespaces. Had no issues before with webpack.

Here is an example:

```
// types.ts
export namespace Test {
  export interface Tester {
    field: string;
  }
}
export interface TestInterface {
  field: string;
}
```

```
// index.ts
import {Test, TestInterface} from './types.ts';
```

If I do it like this I get an error saying:
`'Test' is not exported by ./types.ts`

However it works correctly if I change the code to this:

```
// index.ts
import * as Types from './types.ts';
import Test = Types.Test;
import TestInterface = Types.TestInterface;
```

Is there another option besides having to do a wildcard import then reassigning each individually?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out you have to use the keyword `type` on the import.

```
import type {Test, TestInterface} from './types.ts';
```

I somehow skipped over the few lines that talked about it in the documentation.
https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript